# How can memoize be implemented in pure functional languages?

Tags: functional-programming, memoization

One advantage of pure functions is that their inputs fully determine their outputs, allowing the result to be cached for later use. However, I don't see how this can be implemented without either:

- mutable global state to store a cache (not possible in a truly pure functional language)
- threading a cache through all computations (unwieldy, even with a monad)
- some kind of annotation with run-time support (a bit hacky, but probably sufficient)
- a very clever run-time (might be unpredictable and have other overheads)

How is memoize commonly implemented in pure functional languages?

Comment: The only ones I've seen so far used #1 - a global state.

Comment: You can rely on lazy evaluation, i.e. your pure function returns an infinite list that covers all possible values, but only those you actually use are calculated and memoized on demand. This would be a clever evaluation strategy then..

Comment: N.B. that with option #1 mutability is not required: persistent data structures may have new elements added and if the function being memoized is referentially transparent (and it should be if you're memoizing it) then you'll never be modifying an existing entry in the cache. I don't think global state is necessary as long as you can store state in a closure.

Comment: @JaredSmith the data-structure would be immutable but the pointer to the current version of that data structure would change more inputs to the function are memoized

Comment: #1, but with mutable *local* state. The internal state of the memoized function is mutated, but the function remains pure from an outside perspective.
Example in F#: https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/1e5b71e52cd67733937063fff1c16f7b

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled myself through optimizing some frequently recalculated computations in a pure functional style (though the language I'm using is actually *not* purely functional), so I figured I'd share my findings.

In a way, the answer is already in the question, as it lists all possible implementation approaches. Assuming that #1 is out of the question when using a purely functional language, options #2, #3, and #4 are all valid possibilities, and it depends a little on the context which option would be typically used.

For my particular problem (repeated re-calculation of type information), I opted for option #2 using a [State monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad), with the cache contents being the state that is being carried through. Luckily in my case, all functions/methods that needed caching had the same return type, so I replaced the original return type with the new state monad (which consisted of the original type and the cache).  As you alluded, it turned out to be a pretty involved refactoring, but in the end the exterior interface did not look much different, except for the different return type.

I also considered option #3, i.e. by moving the problem into some kind of "meta-space" outside of the actual function execution, for example by using Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP). I'm working in a JVM-based language so I had a good look at [Spring's `@Cacheable`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) and other similar solutions like [`jcabi-aspects`](https://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-cacheable.html). Other languages have similar options, e.g. Python's [`@cached_property`](https://pypi.org/project/cached-property/). It's a pretty transparent way of adding caching without changing much else, but in my case this solution didn't interact well with some previous design choices I'd made (I'm already using a different dependency injection framework that makes use of AOP, and introducing a second DI solution would have been complicated).

Lastly, option #4 is something that one would find at the language implementation level. A purely functional programming language, could technically cache any function result using its respective input arguments as cache key. I am not aware of any programming language that does this automatically, but (manually) creating memoized functions is possible in common functional languages like Clojure and Haskell. Doing this automatically, is probably difficult as one would have to come up with a caching and cache eviction strategy that provides a reasonable trade-off between time and memory for many different use case scenarios.